# Tons of mail windows opened because of no preferred outgoing server

Tags: macos, mail.app, mojave

I don't use mail normally. So today when I open my app, this caught me by surprise[image]

I selected one of the server and then close the mail window, but there are just so many to go through.

My questions:

1) The email are seemingly created based on some of my calendar events. Why they tried to send me emails?

2) How can I efficiently close all these windows in one go, instead of making a selection of outgoing server than close a mail window?

I have tried to quit the mail app from its context menu of the Dock, but it just forces one of the mail window to the foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Trying to send you emails because, email is one of the options for Reminders in Calendar.

   - To get rid of this for existing events, simplest is just to manually one-by-one change the reminder setting. Alternative would be (1) export the calendar to a file, (2) Make a backup copy for when you mess up step 3 and regret it bitterly at step 4, (3) edit the file to search and replace reminders (4) delete your calendar (5) import the edited events.
   - To get rid of this for future events, I think you just have to change the reminder setting once; on your one next new event. Then it will remember.
2. Force-quit with  ⌥⌘`esc`. If that really really doesn't work, logout.
3. Worst case, avoid the future annoyance either by telling the Mail app your email details; or open Mail app -> `Preferences` to tell it what program you actually do use for email.